# python3 single column dataframe compare

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 pandas data frames, each one with single column ('id') as per below, id column may have duplicates also.
**df1:**

**id**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

**df2:**

**id**

```
1
2
3
```

**Output:**
**id**

```
4
5
```

I'm reading 2 files, i'm not able to achieve desired output using merge. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
colnames = ['id']
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'file1.csv', names=colnames)
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'file2.csv', names=colnames)
###df = df1.merge(df2, how='right')
```

Comment: Use `isin`: `df1.loc[~df1.id.isin(df2.id)]`

Comment: Thank you for quick response, this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `set`:

```
>>> set(df1['id']) - set(df2['id'])
{4, 5}
>>>
```

Or:

```
>>> df1.loc[~df1['id'].isin(df2['id'])]
   id
3   4
4   5
>>>
```